# How to get associated image name when using predict_generator() in keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

```
test_batches = ImageDataGenerator(
    preprocessing_function=preprocess_input
).flow_from_directory(test_path,target_size=(224,224),batch_size=1,class_mode=None,shuffle = "false")
prediction = model.predict_generator(test_batches, steps=1, verbose=1)
np.argmax(prediction)
```

So here I am testing one image by using step_size=1 and steps=1. Whenever I run this I get different predictions, which means it's not picking the same image every time. How can I check the image name?

EDIT: Here's another attempt to explain the problem I am facing:

```
test_batches = ImageDataGenerator(
    preprocessing_function=preprocess_input
).flow_from_directory(test_path,target_size=(224,224),batch_size=2,class_mode=None,shuffle = "false")
prediction = model.predict_generator(test_batches, steps=1, verbose=2)
```

The prediction variable has two arrays of prediction probabilities. How can I know for which images these predictions are for?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keras flowFromDirectory get file names as they are being generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41715025/keras-flowfromdirectory-get-file-names-as-they-are-being-generated)

Comment: @Asymptote did you manage to associate the filenames with the prediction scores from predict_generator. Can you share your code for reference please? I also have the same requirement

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- If your goal is to get acquainted with keras ImageDataGenerators:

If you want your generator to always return the **same image** (for reproducability):

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import numpy as np

data_dir = 'path/to/image/directory'  # path to the directory where the images are stored
index = 0  # select a number here

ig = ImageDataGenerator()
gen = ig.flow_from_directory(data_dir, batch_size=1)  # if you want batch_size > 1 you need to
                                                      # add as many indices as your batch_size.
image, label = gen._get_batches_of_transformed_samples(np.array([index]))
image_name = gen.filenames[index]
# do whatever you want with your image and label
```

If you want your generator to always return a **random image** but know which one it is I would suggest doing the following:

```
index = next(gen.index_generator)
image, label = gen._get_batches_of_transformed_samples(index)
image_name = gen.filenames[index]
```

- If you want to see how `predict_generator` works, however none of these approaches will help you out. The only thing I can think of is editing the `DirectoryIterator` [code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/preprocessing/image.py#L1429).

For example you could add a line that prints the name of the image you are passing. I would suggest adding the following statement after [line 1434](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/preprocessing/image.py#L1434):

```
print(fname)
```

Comment: Honestly, I want to use predict_generator(), I just want to know which image it used for predictions. predict_generator() only returns predictions. I want to build association between filenames and predictions. I am pretty sure I am missing something very basic.

Comment: Unfortunately if you want to use the `predict_generator()` I don't think there is an easier way than to change the line I told you about.

Comment: Thank you, I managed to understand what you explained above. I can build association and yes without using predict_generator (I don't think there's an easier way).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the generator.filename attribute

```
image_name=test_batch.filenames[0]
```

Comment: This won't work, it will just give the first image from the generator's filenames list, not the first image that it returns.