# Way to print invalid filenames for generator in keras

Tags: keras

I have a big dataframe that I pass to a

```
generator.flow_from_dataframe(df,...)
```

but when I run it, I have

```
UserWarning: Found 52 invalid image filename(s) in x_col="image". These filename(s) will be ignored.
  .format(n_invalid, x_col)
```

There is a way to print these invalid image filenames or to understand their indexes in the df?

Comment: What does it mean to "Found 52 invalid image filename(s)"? Does it mean that the files are there or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a similar error, bypassed it by using the flag `validate_filenames=False` in the `flow_from_dataframe` method

Currently, AFAIK there is no way to list the file names from the data-frame that do not map to the image directory, in Keras

You can write your python method to list the differences or there must be a 3rd party library which does the same

Comment: Thanks. I faced this problem but using "validate_filenames=False", I solved that problem.

Answer (score 1):

The issue can be fixed by specifying the absolute path for images within the dataframe.
Assuming :

1. The dataframe df contains two columns - Image(X) & Class(Y)
2. Images are stored in train_dir
   [(Image dataframe structure)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SE9WU.png)

```
# Specifying absolute path for images in the data frame

abs_file_names = []

for file_name in df['Image']:
    tmp = os.path.abspath(train_dir+os.sep+file_name)
    abs_file_names.append(tmp)

# update dataframe
df['Image'] = abs_file_names

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255.,validation_split=0.25)

a = datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe = df,
    train_dir=None,
    x_col="Image",
    y_col="Class",
    weight_col=None,
    target_size=(150, 150),
    color_mode="rgb",
    classes=None,
    class_mode="categorical",
    batch_size=32,
    shuffle=True,
    seed=None,
    save_to_dir=None,
    save_prefix="",
    save_format=None,
    subset=None,
    interpolation="nearest",
    validate_filenames=True,
)
```

Useful resources for more info :

- https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#flow_from_dataframe
- [Keras flowFromDirectory get file names as they are being generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41715025/keras-flowfromdirectory-get-file-names-as-they-are-being-generated)
- https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/6701f27afa62712b34a17d4b0ff879156b0c7937/keras_preprocessing/image/dataframe_iterator.py#L267
- https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/issues/92

Answer (score 0):

```
df['image'] = df['image']+'.jpg'
```

Use the above code to convert the names of the images into filenames before inputting "image" in `x_col` parameter in the `flow_from_dataframe` function. This is what worked for me.